# I can't get my button to center on my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've tried a ton of different tricks, including display: block;, display: table; margin: 0 auto; I really don't know what else to try at this point. Here's the link to the whole repl.it:

https://repl.it/@joshing_you/Fortnite-Battle-Royale-Quiz-App

Here's the specific javascript code snippet:

```
function questionGenerator (score, multipleChoiceQues, completedQuestions) {
      return `
    <section class="question-section">
      <h3>${multipleChoiceQues.question}</h3>

      <form class="question-form">
        <fieldset>
          <label for="ans" class="choice">
            <input type="radio" name="option" required>
            <span>${multipleChoiceQues.answerOne}</span>
          </label>
          <br>
          <label for="ans" class="choice">
            <input type="radio" name="option">
            <span>${multipleChoiceQues.answerTwo}</span>
          </label>
          <br>
          <label for="ans" class="choice">
            <input type="radio" name="option">
            <span>${multipleChoiceQues.answerThree}</span>
          </label>
          <br>
          <label for="ans" class="choice">
            <input type="radio" name="option">
            <span>${multipleChoiceQues.answerFour}</span>
          </label>
          <br>
        </fieldset>
        <button class="answer-submit">SUBMIT</button>
      </form>
    </section>

    <section class="question-and-score">
      <span class="currentQuestion">Question: ${multipleChoiceQues.num}/10</span>
      <span class="currentScore">Score: ${score}/${completedQuestions}</span>
    </section>`;
    }
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.answer-submit {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100px;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: position absolute will never work with align-items

Comment: are you using bootstrap?

Answer (score 2):

```css
button{
display:block;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<button>Hi! It's Worked.</button>
```

Try this one. Hope It helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Button's are inline elements (`inline-block`) by default, which is why `margin: 0 auto` is not working; and also why it does work when you set the button's `display` to `block`.

However that could have potentially undesired side effects (namely the element fills the width of the container).

Your best bet would be to simply wrap the button in a div and apply `text-align: center;` to that `div`:

```css
.buttons {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
    <button class="answer-submit">SUBMIT</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `margin: 0 auto;` with absolute positioned items. Set your left and right to 0;

```
.answer-submit {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```css
.answer-submit {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<button class='answer-submit'>Click</button>
```